# Confused by IIS and ASP.Net configurations

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

We created a simple ASP.Net (.Net 4) project with 2 pages and they're containing nothing but `Response.Write(DateTime.Now);`. Using *[WCAT](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86))* we simulated 6000 requests to the server (server and client are different machines). Soon, all requests hanged in the request queue.

Server information: Intel i3 CPU (4 cores), 4GB RAM, 64bit, IIS 7.5.

We've changed these properties in machine.config, but no changes:

```
<processModel autoConfig="false"
  maxWorkerThreads = "4000"
  maxIoThreads = "4000"
  minWorkerThreads = "2000"
  minIoThreads = "2000"
  requestQueueLimit = "8000" />
```

Comment: At what piece of code were they hanging? Pause the debugger to find out.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, as I said we've monitored requests and saw the results.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with the code why is your app broken, then? "Hanging" certainly is not expected behavior. IIS would be a useless webserver if it was randomly pausing requests. Something *you* did is causing it, make no mistake about it.

Comment: ASP.NET locks the session during the lifetime of the pages. Try  Disabling the Session state in your web.config and see what happens: <sessionState mode="Off" />

Comment: @Alireza We just turned session state off but no changes, again. And, also, we need to use sessions in our real application.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit AppPool?

Comment: @Alireza Yes, `enable 32-bit applications` is `false`.

Comment: How can I get WCAT and test the problem myself?

Comment: @Alireza Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT) http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86)

Comment: Thanks. Now I need the scenario, the settings and you command line to simulate the load here

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268 Please learn some calculation rules, instead of using your insane numbers.

Answer (score 0):

" In this new mode, the CLR Threadpool is still controlled by the processModel configuration settings (autoConfig, maxWorkerThreads, maxIoThreads, minWorkerThreads, and minIoThreads). And autoConfig is still enabled, but its modifications to httpRuntime/minFreeThreads and httpRuntime/minLocalRequestFreeThreads **do nothing, since the application-level queues do not exist** "

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx